# Having issue with running my csv file in my jmeter

Tags: jmeter

```
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: NewOffenderInfo Alias: NewOffenderInfo@27949741 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File NewOffenderInfo must exist and be readable
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.createBufferedReader(FileServer.java:422)
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getReader(FileServer.java:388)
    at org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getParsedLine(FileServer.java:379)
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.CSVDataSet.iterationStart(CSVDataSet.java:196)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:405)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:397)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:158)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.nextIsAController(GenericController.java:222)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:176)
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:123)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:87)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:239)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2016/08/30 14:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

If I remove my CSV file and run the script it will work, but as long as I put the csv config , I'm not able to run my script. I set the Recycle on `EOF = False` and Stop Thread on `EOF =True` and `Sharing mode= Current` thread group. can somebody help me find out what is wrong?

Comment: any feedback on answer, if it"s ok you should accept it and upvote so that it's useful to others ? thx

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the path you have mentioned to configure the CSV is correct. As per the exception in Jmeter.log file, it's not able to find the CSV.

Check following things:

1. Name of the file is correct. In case of Unix file names are case sensitive so check the name of the file and name you have mentioned in CSV data set configuration.
2. Keep the CSV file in the same folder where your JMX resides, and just mention file name in CSV dataset config. This avoids confusion in future even if you move the script to any other box.
3. Also make sure in the file there is no new line character at the end of the file. That will result in error.

Answer (score 0):

As the log says:

> File NewOffenderInfo must exist and be readable at

You file is either not here or does not have correct rights.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to include the filename extension (.csv) in the CSV Data Set Config.